# How to select multitple value of object when click on button in Angular selection option dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am placing JSON result in option list of selection dropdown menu

```
[
{
    "id": "1596700684533_",
    "name": "Usman Abbas Ghulam Abbas",
    "fcm": "344"
},
{
    "id": "1596700972722_",
    "name": "Muhammad Ali",
    "fcm": "0"
},
{
    "id": "1596702420255_",
    "name": "Abdul Hannan Abdul Mannan",
    "fcm": "234"
}
]
```

- how can i select full object and values of object like id and fcm both when click on button

my component.htlm code is

```
<select (change)="Selected($event)">
              <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.fcm">
                {{group.name}}
              </option>
            </select>
```

currently on button click i can get either one value id or fcm

```
Selected(event: any){
//update the ui
this.selectedName = event.target.value;
//this.selectedId = event.targent.value.id
this.hide=false;



}


getVal(){
  this.button=this.selectedName;
  console.log("hre is selected values for option " + this.selectedName);
 

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the value of the option to be the `id`. In your `(change)` event emitter handler, find the Item with that id

See Below code [Link to stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fsdhpl)

```html
<select (change)="Selected($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.id">
    {{group.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Typescript file

```typescript
  Selected($event) {
    const selectedObject = this.groups.find(({id}) => id === event.target['value'])
    this.selectedName = selectedObject.name
    this.selectedId = selectedObject.id
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st Way(set group instead of group.fcm)

```
<option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group">
```

2nd Way(Get the fcm / id and filter the existing record on top it)

```
<option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.id">
```

Component

```
 Selected(event: any){
  this.selectedObj= data.filter(item => item.id = event.target.value)
  this.hide=false;
}
```

I think 2nd way will give you much more control over your data set and ui visibility.

Comment: i have tried first Way by placing <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group">
its return me object, how can i get values from object

Comment: You can try 2nd way. The same answer posted later.